# c# найти и изменить строку в файле

Tags: c#, winforms, сериализация, десериализация

Пытаюсь сделать редактор cfg файла (конфиг для коммутатора), в котором нужно изменить 2 значения. Суть такова - открыть конфиг (указать путь до файла), в текстбоксы вписать ip и milticast_ip и нажать "заменить", далее программа ищет строчку, содержащую часть команды, удаляет ее и вписывает заново часть команды уже с имеющимся значением из текстбокса.

```
private void selectBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "CFG files (*.cfg)|*.cfg";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                cfgPath.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
        }

        private void replaceBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            string ipKomm = ipTxt.Text;
            if (cfgPath.Text != "")
            {
                string line = null;
                string line_to_delete = "config ipif System ipaddress";
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cfgPath.Text)){
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cfgPath.Text)){
                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null){
                            if (String.Compare(line, line_to_delete) == 0)
                                continue;
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("Выберите файл для редактирования!");

            }
```

Сначала я выбираю нужный файл, он записывается, как путь в текстбокс, ниже в форме есть еще 2 текстбокса, в которые вписываю нужные параметры и кнопка "заменить" (replaceBtn_Click) - при нажатии проверяю наличие пути в текстбоксе до файла, ищу удаляемую строку и получаю ошибку в строке "StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cfgPath.Text))" ... Подскажите, что я делаю не так или как мне реализовать то, что я хочу сделать?

Comment: .cfg файл (вернее его содержимое) выложите для примера, возможно есть путь по проще! Как минимум лучше.

Comment: @Monomax https://hkar.ru/XP2X в конфиге много текста, в основном команды для работы коммутатора, вот часть из них. там есть такая строчка "config ipif System ipaddress IP..." мне нужно как раз и заменить этот айпи + есть еще одна команда ниже, в которой есть мультикаст айпи. Смысл заключается в том, чтобы при перепрошивке коммутатора можно было быстрее отредактировать конфиг и не искать в нем нужные параметры

Comment: искать в темной комнате черного кота, да тем более что его нет, задача весьма сложная, поэтому прошу выложить пример конфигурационного файла! По сути, у вашей цели можно достичь. решив следующие задачи: Считать файл, найти нужную строку, изменить строку, перезаписать ВЕСЬ файл измененными данными!

Comment: @Monomax https://yadi.sk/i/jBJroW13X1mSFA ссылка на конфиг

Comment: Я конечно надеялся на xml, но и с этим работать можно, по сути у вас есть файл с разметкой, где у вас "#" начало раздела, разделы отделены между собой новой строкой. При этом есть заголовок и признак окончания файла. С другой стороны, если четко известен текст, который надо заменить (или хотя бы часть текста), и такой текст уникальный (не повторяется нигде), то можно файл считать в переменную `string` , затем использовать `Replase`, после чего выполнить запись обратно в файл. Но такое возможно если текст уникальный, судя по всему, вам понадобится использовать первую часть данного комментария.

Comment: @Monomax мне бы пример кода, не уверен, что я понял, как это делать(

Comment: Читаете весь файл в массив строк (File.ReadAllLines) меняете нужные строки и перезаписываете файл. Просто заменить часть текста в середине файла без перезаписи получится только в одном случае, если вы меняете строго N старых символов, на N новых, и при этом используется кодировка с фиксированным числом байт на один символ.